# How to get value to text box according to selected value with reference to database in php?

Tags: javascript, php, database, codeigniter

Below is my database value

```
+----+--------------------+-------------+
| id | type               | rate        |
+----+--------------------+-------------+
|  1 | Accord|Corola|Tata | Out|Loc|Out |
+----+--------------------+-------------+
```

I exploded the values of `type` column and displayed it in `select tag` in `view` page successfully.

I have another `textbox` where I need to display `rate` according to selected `type` position.

```
<input type="text" id="rate">
```

How to get the required value in `textbox` when we select the `dropdown` `type` value?

I'm using Code Igniter framework.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store rate value in select tag only as value as given below.

```
<select id="type_select">
<option value="Out">Accord</option>
<option value="Loc">Corola</option>
<option value="Out">Tata</option>
</select>
```

onchange of `select` in jquery get the rate value and display it.

**Javascript code :**

```
$( "#type_select" ).change(function() {
  var rate = $( "#type_select option:selected" ).val();
  $("#rate").val(rate);
});
```

Comment: There I'm generating `dropdown` dynamically. Cant assign the value like that.

Comment: Create an array from that PHP array in JS, create a function of JS and call it on onSelect, get the value from js array and show it on text area using js or jquery.

Comment: When you populate the value for type from database like that u have do for rate column.  <?php $type = explode("|",$type_db);$rate=explode("|",$rate_db);$i=0;oreach($type as $val){?> <option value="<?php echo $rate[$i];?>"><?php echo $val;?></option>
<?php $i++; }?>

Comment: Your given code is done by JQuery. But the problem I'm facing is I'm using AJAX to load whole page. Only JavaScript can be implemented. JQuery wont work. How do do that in Javascript?

Comment: Its working fine but when I want to submit this form, the value of `select` tag is going but i dont want to sent the value I want to send Accord or Tata etc..

Comment: create hidden field in form for type when dropdown value selected set that value in hidden field and then it can used as post variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
$types=explolde("|",$type);    
$rates=explolde("|",$rate);
$dataArray = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($types as $value){
 $dataArray[$value] = $rates[$i++]; // I assume size of both array is same,  
 //you may check additional exception handling.
}
```

`$dataArray` has the actual value, get the value from this array based on your requirements since you have a map now.

Comment: I want to display only one value in `textbox`. By above code it is displaying all three values.

Answer (score 0):

can you try add a selection event in javascript on the  selection and load the corresponding rate by ajax.

Add event like

```
$(document).on("change","#type",function(e){
  var type=$(this).find("option:selected").val();
    //load ajax call
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: mtdf, // HTTP method POST or GET
      url: url, //Where to make Ajax calls
      dataType: "json", // Data tr_, HTML, json etc.
      data:{type:type}, //data to the server,
      success: function (response) {
        //console.log(response);                    
      },
      error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a try

```
<?php 
$type = 'Accord|Corola|Tat';
$rate = 'Out|Loc|Out';

    $new_type = explode('|',$type);
    $new_rate = explode('|',$rate);

echo "<select onchange='getValue()' id='theSelect'>";
for($x=0;$x<count($new_rate);$x++){
    echo "<option value = '".$new_rate[$x]."' > ".$new_type[$x]." </option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

<script>

    function getValue(){
        var valSelect = $("#theSelect").val();
            $("#rate").val(valSelect);
    }

</script>


<input type="text" id="rate">
```

Comment: when we try to submit the form the `value` of `select` tag will insert to db. But how to send the vehicle name in that?